# Virtual Machine Backups

Tags: backup-restoration, images

Say I have a client that is running 2 VMWare virtual servers on the one box. Is there an easy way to backup the entire OS image so that if the hardware was to fail, the virtual OS could be put onto another box running the same VMWare software.

Also, for bonus points, is there a way to send incremental backups over the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Vmware?  Vmware server, the free ESXi, a licensed version?

Comment: Agree with Zoredache.. need to know what version of VMWare you are running here to start with different possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider (and this may depend largely on the version of VMware you are using) configuring an NFS share for the datastores. Then you migrate the virtual servers to the NFS share. If the server fails, you connect another one and import the servers to that, then start them up.

There are a heck of a lot of variables though, and we need considerably more information about your environment - version of VMware, roles of the servers (NFS may not give adequate disk performance), etc...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of those applications that image an entire OS to a remote server continuously and incrementaly?

I use the (free version of) [Macricum Reflect](http://www.filehippo.com/download_macrium_reflect/) to constantly image my OS to a NAS, but there are many enterprise level applications that can do this for you. Just install them in every VM (or install in your original VM image) and set to automatic backup.